# FlexSlider: How to change Style for multiple direction Navs?

Tags: css, flexslider

I am using a flexslider as a main Slider with default styles and another flexslider carousel on another page. But needs different direction navs styles for carousel.
By default the class for direction nav is ".flex-direction-nav a" in flexslider.css. And we can edit it. But how can we assign another class to some other directional nav?
Same is with control Nav. I want to hide control nav of carousel on @max-width 450px but not for main slider....So how can I address control nav just for a specific slider in CSS?

```
.flex-direction-nav a {
      width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 4px; 
      display: block; background: url(../img/bg_direction_nav.png) no-repeat 0 0;
      position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 10; cursor: pointer; 
      text-indent:-9999px; opacity: 0; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}

.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
      background-position: 100% 0; right: -36px; }

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
      left: -36px;}
```

The above is example from default Flexslider CSS which is addressing the .flex-direction-nav class and this class is generated from JS. But How can we add another class eg. ".flex-direction-nav-1" so we can change its styles and positions via CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Use the default CSS for the slider/carousel

```
/* Direction Nav */
.flex-direction-nav {height: 0;}
.flex-direction-nav a {width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url('/images/system/bg_direction_nav.png') no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; z-index: 3; cursor: pointer; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
```

Then give the carousel you want to behave differently its own id and then apply CSS to that id like this:

```
#carousel .flex-direction-nav {height: 0;}
#carousel .flex-direction-nav a {width: 30px; height: 30px; margin: -20px 0 0; display: block; background: url('/images/system/bg_direction_nav_sml.png') no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; top: 40px; z-index: 3; cursor: pointer; border: solid 1px #c8c8c8; text-indent: -9999px; opacity: 1; -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
```